# How to change internal function in MendelianRandomization function in order to change decimal places in output?

Tags: r

I am running this function on MAC computer where I installed this function:

```
  library(MendelianRandomization)
  EggerObject <- mr_egger(MRInputObject,robust = FALSE,penalized = FALSE,correl = FALSE,distribution = "normal",alpha = 0.05)
```

but the output for p values has only 3 decimal places, I would like to extend it say to 10 decimal places:

```
> EggerObject

MR-Egger method
```

(variants uncorrelated, random-effect model)

Number of Variants =  88

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
      Method Estimate Std Error  95% CI        p-value
    MR-Egger    0.044     0.009  0.027,  0.061   0.000
 (intercept)   -0.041     0.004 -0.049, -0.033   0.000
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I was looking in their documentation https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MendelianRandomization/versions/0.4.1/topics/decimals

but I am not sure how to apply this.

I tried this:

```
> EggerObject <- mr_egger(MRInputObject,robust = FALSE,penalized = FALSE,correl = FALSE,distribution = "normal",alpha = 0.05, decimals(number = p-value, places = 10))
Error in format(round(number, places), nsmall = places) : 
  object 'p' not found
```

EDIT:

```
> str(EggerObject)
Formal class 'Egger' [package "MendelianRandomization"] with 23 slots
  ..@ Model       : chr "random"
  ..@ Exposure    : chr "exposure"
  ..@ Outcome     : chr "outcome"
  ..@ Robust      : logi FALSE
  ..@ Penalized   : logi FALSE
  ..@ Correlation : logi [1, 1] NA
  ..@ Estimate    : num 0.0441
  ..@ StdError.Est: num 0.00861
  ..@ CILower.Est : num 0.0273
  ..@ CIUpper.Est : num 0.061
  ..@ Pvalue.Est  : num 2.92e-07
  ..@ Intercept   : num -0.041
  ..@ StdError.Int: num 0.00432
  ..@ CILower.Int : num -0.0494
  ..@ CIUpper.Int : num -0.0325
  ..@ Pvalue.Int  : num 0
  ..@ Pleio.pval  : num 0
  ..@ Causal.pval : num 2.92e-07
  ..@ Alpha       : num 0.05
  ..@ SNPs        : int 88
  ..@ RSE         : num 8.79
  ..@ Heter.Stat  : num [1:2] 6649 0
  ..@ I.sq        : num 0.959
```

Comment: what do you get with `str(EggerObject)`?  That should tell you where to find the value so you can format it to your desired precision.

Comment: Thank you so much, I added that results to my post. Please advise what do I do from here?

Comment: From the result of that command can I say that for MR-Egger method p value is 2.92e-07 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EggerObject` is an "S4" list and so you can access the value of the `Pvalue.Est` item using the S4 access function `"@"`. (It's like "$" for ordinary S3 objects.) The explicit `print` function allows you control of the degree of precision:

```
 print( EggerObject@Pvalue.Est, digits=10)
```

It's possible that there is an accessor-function for objects of class-"Egger". If such a function exists it would be preferable, since the package author likely knows of potential pitfalls with use of different components of such an object.